# Condition number matrix matrix multiplication

Tags: numerical-methods

can anybody tell me the condition number of 
$X \cdot Y$ with  $X \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times N}, Y \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times P}$.
I tried to describe the matrix multiplication by a sum of many multiplications ($a=M \cdot N \cdot P$), which each has a condition number of $\kappa=\frac{(x_i+y_i)^2}{|x_i y_i|}$, but do not know how to connect them.

Or may it be just the product of the condition numbers of the two matrices: $\kappa_1 \cdot \kappa_2 $ ?

Comment: What definition of *condition number* do you have for non square (singular) matrices?

Comment: Isn't there a condition number for non square matrices? I think about the relative condition which tells me something about maximal error the matrix matrix product can have.

Comment: Do you want the condition of $(X,Y) \mapsto XY$ or the condition of $X\mapsto XY$ for a fixed $Y$?

Comment: The first one, so you were right with your answer

Answer (score 1):

I will write it using the Frobenius norm $\|\cdot\| = \|\cdot\|_F$, as it makes the result looks more like the scalar result. Also, I use the norm $\|(X,Y)\| = \sqrt{ \|X\|^2 + \|Y\|^2 }$ on $\mathbb R^{M\times N} \times \mathbb R^{N\times P}$.

Let $f(X,Y) = XY$. Then, the differential of $f$ is given by
$$ Df(X,Y)[H,K] = XH + KY $$
Thus, for $\|(H,K)\| = 1$ we have
\begin{align} 
\| Df(X,Y)[H,K] \| 
&\le \|XH\| + \|KY\| \\
&\le \|X\|\|H\| + \|K\|\|Y\| \\
&\le \sqrt{ \|X\|^2 + \|Y\|^2 } \sqrt{ \|H\|^2 + \|K\|^2 } = \|(X,Y)\|.
\end{align}
That is, the operator norm of $Df(X,Y)$ is bounded by $\|(X,Y)\|$.

Thus, the condition number is bounded as following:
$$  \kappa_f(X,Y) = \frac{\|Df(X,Y)\|\|(X,Y)\|}{\|f(X,Y)\|} \le \frac{\|(X,Y)\|^2}{\|XY\|} = \frac{\|X\|^2 + \|Y\|^2}{\|XY\|}. $$